# logging attribute asctime generate local time

Tags: python, logging

I'm using logging for my project and the format is

```
'format': '%(asctime)s %(message)s'
```

however, the time didn't equal to my local time. e.g

2013-01-08 11:04:07,383 message
(this is UTC-6 time)

I want to know

1. how to log using my local time
2. how to change time format to 2013-01-08 11:04:07

---

I have fixed it , the problem is that I need to set the  time zone in setting.py !!!

Comment: `logging` uses `localtime` by default. And that doesn't look like a UTC time—it's 2013-10-09 00:15 right now in UTC, so unless you ran that 14 hours ago, it's local. If it's the _wrong_ local time, maybe you have your timezone set wrong? As for the other part, you just want to eliminate the ",383" milliseconds part, right?

Comment: you should mention in the question that you use django and that without it logging produces correct local time. Also don't put an answer in the question, post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter):

> class logging.Formatter(fmt=None, datefmt=None)
>
> Returns a new instance of the Formatter class. The instance is initialized with a format string for the message as a whole, as well as a format string for the date/time portion of a message. If no fmt is specified, '%(message)s' is used. If no datefmt is specified, the ISO8601 date format is used.

Also:

> If the formatting string contains `'(asctime)'`, `formatTime()` is called to format the event time.

So, you can either specify a `datefmt`, or create a custom `Formatter` subclass with your own `formatTime` override.

And, if you want to choose between local time and GMT time (or anything else):

> By default, time.localtime() is used; to change this for a particular formatter instance, set the converter attribute to a function with the same signature as time.localtime() or time.gmtime(). To change it for all formatters, for example if you want all logging times to be shown in GMT, set the converter attribute in the Formatter class.

The `format` and `datefmt` arguments can also be passed to [`basicConfig`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), if you're not using an explicit `Formatter`. You can't set a `converter` this way—but you don't have to, because the default is local time.

So:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.error('Out of cheese!')
```

I ran this at 16:11:30 local time, and the output is:

```
2013-01-08 16:11:30 Out of cheese!
```

In fact, it looks like all you're trying to do is knock the milliseconds off the standard time format, which you can do even more simply by just truncating the string:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)-.19s %(message)s')
```

However, I think it makes more sense to specify the date format explicitly.

Comment: it's weird that >>> time.localtime() will print the correct time:time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=11, tm_min=0, tm_sec=45, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=9, tm_isdst=0), but Django logging time is 2013-01-08 20:56:35

Comment: my time.localtime() is correct, but Django logging is UTC-6 time

Comment: @user1687717: That probably means you have a different timezone specified in your Django configs than you're system's actual timezone. They're both doing the right thing, given the information they've been given, but they were given contradictory information.

Comment: I'm using Django's ORM as a standalone in my project and I was having the same issue of incorrect timezone in my logger. Reading the above comments, I figured out that for some reason the timezone in Django's settings.py was changing my logger's timezone. Now my problem is solved, but I still don't know why Django's logging settings are conflicting with mine's.

Comment: thkx for the time saving :-)